# How do I limit certain functions to certain structures in C?

Tags: c, struct

I have my Struct set up like this :

```
typedef struct Graph_
{
    Point2D position;
    double Size_X;
    double Size_Y;
    char* Label;
    NVGcolor Background_Color;
    bool Borders;
    bool Grid;
    int Grid_Scale;
    NVGcolor Grid_Color;
    float Border_Padding;
    void (*init)(NVGcontext* vg, struct Graph_ * graph);
    void (*drawAxes)(NVGcontext* vg, Axis * axis , struct Graph_* graph);
}Graph;
```

and the corresponding methods like this in my header,

```
void InitGraph(NVGcontext* vg, Graph* graph);
void DrawAxes(NVGcontext* vg, Axis* axisObject);
```

I want to limit the said methods only to be called from the parent struct and not directly. Is there a visibility, workaround, in C?
Apologize if this is a noob question.

P.S. I am trying to use the struct as a class in my application.

Comment: You want classes, and private methods.  Use C++.  You can approximate it in C by making the private "methods" static functions, but they will only be callable from within the file that defines them.

Comment: Yeah , I agree but i kinda am stuck with using c here

Comment: Why is the  `struct Graph_` definition in the.h file?  Consider only `typedef struct Graph_ Graph;` in the .h file.  Hide all `struct` members - put the `struct Graph_
{
    Point2D position; ....
    void (*init)(NVGcontext* vg, struct Graph_ * graph);
    void (*drawAxes)(NVGcontext* vg, Axis * axis , struct Graph_* graph);
}` in the .c file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to prevent people from calling those functions directly, but allow people to call them indirectly, via function pointers.  That's easy enough: just don't declare the functions in your header file at all.  You can declare and define the functions in a .c source file, and in that same file you can implement some way to "get" the function pointers, either literally by returning them, or by setting them as members of the Graph struct.  Only those getter/setter functions will be exposed in your header file.

For example, in your header:

```
void SetupGraph(Graph* graph);
```

Then, the implementation in your .c file:

```
static void InitGraph(NVGcontext* vg, Graph* graph) {
    // ...
}

static void DrawAxes(NVGcontext* vg, Axis* axisObject) {
    // ...
}

// public
void SetupGraph(Graph* graph)
{
    graph->init = InitGraph;
    graph->drawAxes = DrawAxes;
}
```

Now, external users of your library can do this:

```
Graph graph;
SetupGraph(&graph);

NVGcontext vg;
graph.init(&vg, &graph);
```

See, they can invoke `InitGraph()` indirectly, via the function pointer that is set by `SetupGraph()`, but they can never call `InitGraph()` directly because they don't know its name.

Comment: correct, I dont quite follow, you have gotten my question correctly. Lets say i have a get function defined in my header file which gives me the pointer to the static function that is in picture. Now i store that as a member in the same struct. I didnt quite understand on how do i call the said function , especially if it has arguments. How will the initial function be abstracted to the specific structure. 

P.S. something like a class implementation

Comment: @AvidJoe: I've expanded my answer, please see.

Answer (score 1):

This is, I think, partly the answer that John gave, but derived a little more abstractly.

I assume that you try to mimic a C++ class with public member functions and private member functions in C.

Public "member functions" must be visible to the "public", if you excuse the pun, and they need a pointer to the struct as one parameter which takes on the role of the implicit `this` pointer in C++. They will be declared in a public header.

In C, you don't have accessibility specifiers, so you can only restrict access to private functions by hiding them. That's OK; only code which implements other functions operating on your struct needs to see them.

There are two ways to hide the functions.

1. You can make the "private" functions (file) static. This is clean because it prevents the compiler from exporting the symbol altogether. Static functions can only be used in the translation unit where they are defined. Because these are files which are part of the "library" for your struct the public simply cannot access them. The linker cannot link to them at all; for other translation units they simply do not exist. But this is also a disadvantage: For large "classes" with many "member functions", all functions using the "private" functions must be in the same source file. (Alternatively you could write an unusual header file which contains the code for static functions and include it wherever you need to access those functions; but that will increase code size and as a general pattern is certainly not recommended.)
2. You create a collection of "private" functions, potentially distributed over several source files. These functions have external linkage and can be used in other translation units. The mechanism to hide them is to put their declarations in a header which is not intended for public inclusion. The public only sees the, well, "public" functions published in a separate header. This would be similar to a C++ interface/implementation design.

   Whether these private functions can theoretically be called by the public (e.g. simply by guessing the name and parameters, or by finding the "private" header and including it) depends on your build system. If you distribute a pre-compiled shared library then you can distinguish your public functions by telling the compiler in a platform specific way to make the symbol externally visible by `__declspec(dllexport)` (Visual C) or `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` (gcc).  Functions not so decorated are not visible outside the library and cannot be linked to. The "private" header would not even be part of the distribution.

   If you simply compile and link a bunch of source and object files though the "private" header must be available for compilation, and the public is free to use them if they include it or guess the function names. If the public using your struct is undisciplined and likes hacks it's likely that code will emerge which relies on the "private" function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the function declarations from the header file and define the functions in the implementation file and add the keyord `static` in front of the declaration.

Comment: If i remove the declaration from the .h file and the target app uses my header. How will one assign the reference to the function in 
```
 void (*init)(NVGcontext* vg, struct Graph_ * graph);
```

right now i am allowing people to assign the function reference as this where this header is included,
```
// Top_Right_G is a struct defined locally.
Top_Right_G.init = InitGraph;
Top_Right_G.init(vg, &Top_Right_G);
```

Comment: @AvidJoe I would define an (exported) initialization function which sets each function pointer field to the correct function.